# Drawable Backgrounds on Lollipop and Lower Devices ResourcesNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am using custom button background in my app by creating it in drawable folder like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@color/otp_gray"/>
   <padding android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
   <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

and my xml file where this drawable is used:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/app_btn_bkg"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
```

It works fine on api 24 device but recently when I tested on a lollipop device (api 21), I got this error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.jjoey.transporterdriver:drawable/app_btn_bkg" (7f08005b)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f08005b a=-1 r=0x7f08005b}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2661)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2576)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3813)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:650)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
```

From my understanding, it has something to do with back compatibility but I don't know how to resolve this. I have read that I should create a separate drawable file for lower api levels but there's no option for that. I am using android studio 3.1.0.

Can anyone help me pls? Thanks.

Comment: can you show how you use that xml file in your button?

Comment: @GoldwynDator, I have included the button layout. Take a look

Comment: did you put your app_btn_bkg xml in the correct folder that is res/drawable ?